# Dynamically Show/Hide flex cards in different Omniscripts

Tags: vlocity

I have a requirement wherein I need to show/hide a flexcard in one script based on a flag or checkbox on another omniscript.

One omniscript is displayed on the salesforce org and the other one is on the portal.

Also, Does someone know good resources to get on speed with OmniStudio?

Comment: Hi Himanshu and welcome. What have you tried so far and where have you got stuck? I feel that it would be useful to share some code of the solution that you attempted.

Comment: No code involved, this is more like a configuration step. I just want to know if that can be done and I am new to Omnistudio, so looking for helpful resources too.

Comment: Have you looked into [Omnistudio trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/get-to-know-omnistudio) by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that's basic info, isn't helping for the use case I have!